# WordPress Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I use the following code in my Single.php file to grab show a different single template file based on what the user is viewing.

```
<?php
    if (in_category('Portfolio')) {
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-work.php');
    }
    elseif (in_category('Blog')) {
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php');
    }
?>
```

The problem is that I am using Child Themes and therefore it will try to include files from the parent theme instead of the child theme. How do I get it to include from the child theme instead?

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly you have to use `STYLESHEETPATH` instead of `TEMPLATEPATH`.